# Two-qutrit preparation using linear optics

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

How can I prepare a two-qutrit product state (let's say $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle|0+2\rangle$ using optics? Do I need a BBO crystal (as I know BBO crystal produces an entangled state), or can I use two separate light sources? I want to prepare it by using a single-photon source.